# QueryBuilder Search for jcr:lastModifiedBy

Tags: aem, query-builder, jcr

I have to search for the value of jcr:lastModifiedBy in AEM[image: JCR data]

I have to search under page which has a jcr:content under which we have components which have a property jcr:lastModifiedBy. Please help

Comment: Is it for one specific page or for all pages which has a jcr:content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this should do the job:

```
path=/content//jcr:content
type=nt:unstructured
property=jcr:lastModifiedBy
property.value=admin
```

You can test also your [query builder](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/dam/customizing_and_extendingcq5dam/query_builder.html) queries also [here](http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html?_charset_=UTF-8&query=path%3D%2Fcontent%2F%2Fjcr%3Acontent%0D%0Atype%3Dnt%3Aunstructured%0D%0Aproperty%3Djcr%3AlastModifiedBy%0D%0Aproperty.value%3Dadmin).